# Custom Comparator in Priority queue in Java

Tags: java, comparator

I am trying to use a priority queue with a custom comparator, However I am not able to achieve my expected functionality.:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;

public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Node>() {
            public int compare(Node a, Node b) {
                if(a.level == b.level) {
                    return a.data - b.data;
                }
                return a.level - b.level;
            }
        });
        
        queue.add(new Node(0,1));
        queue.add(new Node(1,2));
        queue.add(new Node(1,4));
        queue.add(new Node(2,3));
        queue.add(new Node(2,7));
        queue.add(new Node(2,2));
        queue.add(new Node(2,5));
        
        System.out.println(queue);
    }
    
    private static class Node {
        int level;
        int data;
        
        Node(int level, int data) {
            this.level = level;
            this.data = data;
        }
        
        public String toString() {
            return level + ":" + data;
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output = `[0:1, 1:2, 1:4, 2:2, 2:3, 2:5, 2:7]`
Actual output = `[0:1, 1:2, 1:4, 2:3, 2:7, 2:2, 2:5]`

I want the elements in the priority queue to be ordered by the level first then by data.

Comment: `new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Node::getLevel).thenComparing(Node::getData))`

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, to use lambda instead of anonymous inner class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method toString may not display the elements in retrieval order. So, it  doesn't mean that your comparator is incorrect.

The following is written in the [javadoc for PriorityQueu](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) (emphasis is mine):

> This class and its iterator implement all of the optional methods of the  Collection  and  Iterator  interfaces.  The Iterator provided in method
> iterator()  and the Spliterator provided in method  spliterator()
> **are not guaranteed to traverse the elements of  the priority queue in any particular order**. If you need ordered  traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).

It isn't written explicitly here, but toString relies on iterators, therefore elements may not be displayed in the expected orther either.
The toString method is defined in class Collection, and isn't specificly overridden here.

PriorityQueu is probably implemented using a binary heap in an array.
From there, it follows naturally that iteration is made in array order. Displaying elements in the correct order would require removing them from the queue, and is therefore impossible except by sorting a copy somewhere else, what would be too heavy for a simple toString.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the logic is correct, only thing is I am trying to do sysout, then it was showing in the order I have inserted, When I used the remove operation on the priority queue data is coming in expected format.

```
while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(queue.remove());
}
```

**Output:**
0:1
1:2
1:4
2:2
2:3
2:5
2:7